# Content div does not push the footer div

Tags: html, css

I have main content with 3 divs, the third div gets big height and does not push the footer div.

Here is my problem

`<div id="right_column">`this div should be between header and footer`</div>`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/M7VxA/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the float manually by adding a div with property `float: clear;` right after or you can use a [clearfix class like this.](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/M7VxA/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a "Clearfix" aka a div with the property:

```
clear:both
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/M7VxA/7/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#footer
{
    width:300px;
    margin:auto;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    clear: both;
}
```